# How can I create a 2D array of chars with POINTERS in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

I'm trying to create a program which the user inputs the number of items (rows) and give each one of them a name (scanf) with the max of 30 characters.

I want to create this code with pointers of pointers, once that I'm learning this on C.

I'm having some difficulties with the code.

[**Draft of the 2D array.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEHHA.png)

**Code snippet:**

**PS:** `#define MAX 31`

```
  char **items = NULL, *columns = NULL, name[MAX];
  int rows, aux_rows;

  printf("\nNumber of items:\n");
  scanf("%d", &rows);

  items = (char **) malloc(rows * sizeof(char*));

  for (aux_rows = 0; aux_rows < rows; aux_rows++){
    columns[aux_rows] = (char *) malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
  }

  for (aux_rows = 0; aux_rows < rows; aux_rows++){
    printf("\nName of item %d:\n", (aux_rows + 1));
    scanf("%s", name);
    *items[aux_rows] = name;
  }
```

Comment: You can't copy arrays with a simple assignment statement. Use the `strcpy` function. Also, change `scanf("%s", name);` to `scanf("%30s", name)` to prevent evil users from overflowing the `name` array.

Comment: The expression `*items[aux_rows]` will dereference the pointer which is pointing to the first character, so it will yield a single character. This is not what you want. As already stated, you want to use `strcpy` instead.

Comment: @user3386109: In this case, it would probably be better to use `fgets` instead of `scanf`, especially if the "Name of item" can consist of more than one word (e.g. `"candy bar"`). The function `scanf` with the `%s` conversion format specifier will only read a single word.

Comment: https://asciiflow.com/ is nice to generate simple graphics. Better than using png files.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for your suggestion. I didn't know this trick. I'll definitely use it!

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thanks, I didn't know the `strcpy` function as well. I plan using `scanf` anyway, the items should have only one word.

Comment: @Franck That's a great tool! I'm bookmarking it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items` was allocated and not `columns`. And use `strcpy` to copy the characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 31

int main()
{
    char **items = NULL, *columns = NULL, name[MAX];
    int rows, aux_rows;

    printf("\nNumber of items:\n");
    scanf("%d", &rows);

    items = (char **)malloc(rows * sizeof(char *));

    for (aux_rows = 0; aux_rows < rows; aux_rows++)
    {
        items[aux_rows] = malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
    }

    for (aux_rows = 0; aux_rows < rows; aux_rows++)
    {
        printf("\nName of item %d:\n", (aux_rows + 1));
        scanf("%s", name);
        strcpy(items[aux_rows], name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc array2d.c
$ ./a.out      

Number of items:
2

Name of item 1:
Hello 

Name of item 2:
World!
$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
*items[aux_rows] = name;
```

is wrong on two counts.

Both `*` and `[]` dereference their unary operand. If `items` is a `char **`, `items[n]` is a `char *`, and `*items[n]` is a `char`.

This attempts to assign an array to the first element of each buffer.

Secondly, arrays cannot be copied by assignment. Use `strcpy` to copy strings from one buffer to another.

That said, you could simply read your strings directly into the pre-allocated buffers, and do away with the temporary buffer.

---

In this line,

```
columns[aux_rows] = (char *) malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
```

`columns` should be `items`.

---

Some things of note:

`sizeof (char)` is guaranteed to be `1`. Its use is superfluous.

The return of `malloc` [should not be cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2505965) in C.

`malloc` can fail. `scanf` can fail. You should get in the habit of not ignoring return values.

`scanf("%s", ...)` is as [dangerous as `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2505965). At a minimum, use *field-width specifiers* to limit input (should be the size of your buffer minus one).

```
char foo[128];
if (1 != scanf("%127s", foo))
    /* handle error */;
```

---

Note that using the `%s` limits input to not contain any whitespace. `scanf` in general is a [terrible tool](https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html), consider a line based approach using `fgets`.

With that said, the minimum changes to make this reasonably safe:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 31

void die(const char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t rows;

    printf("Number of items: ");

    if (1 != scanf("%zu", &rows))
        die("Failed to read input.");

    char **items = malloc(sizeof *items * rows);

    if (!items)
        die("Failed to allocate memory.");


    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        if (!(items[i] = malloc(MAX)))
            die("Failed to allocate row.");

        printf("Name of item %zu: ", i + 1);

        if (1 != scanf("%30s", items[i]))
            die("Failed to read item input.");
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        puts(items[i]);
        free(items[i]);
    }
}
```